# Split a generator, process independently and zip again

Tags: python, generator

how would I do this?

```
sample_generator = get_sample_generator() # This generator yields tuples (label(i), data(i))


label_generator = ???
data_generator = ???

processed_data_generator = process_data_generator(data_generator)

processed_sample_generator = zip(label_generator, processed_data_generator) # Labels and corresponding data again as tupel (label(i), processed_data(i))
```

Obviously I can not just map() the sample_generator into the label and data generator since both would move the sample_generator forward...

Comment: is it too big to create a list from it?

Comment: You can't split a generator in this sense. To access each second item of your two element tuple, you need to consume `sample_generator`

Comment: Why do you want to do it this way?

Comment: And shouldn't the `zip` use `processed_data_generator`?

Comment: You are right. I changed it. 
I have an existing API which I cannot change. This API provides process_data_generator()
Also in my own interest I wanted to know whether something like this, which can easily implemented with streams (for example reactive extensions), could be possible with generators...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `itertools.tee` to split a generator into 2. You would still need the individual processes to split the resulting value.

```
from itertools import count

def generator():
    for c in count():
        yield 'label {}'.format(c), 'data {}'.format(c)

from itertools import tee

label_generator, data_generator = tee(generator())

print("labels:")
for _ in range(5):
    print(next(label_generator)[0])
print()
print("data:")
for _ in range(5):
    print(next(data_generator)[1])
```

Comment: This seems alright. Instead of using individual processes I guess I also could use ```map(lamda x: x[0], label_generator)``` and same for the data.

Answer (score 1):

Use `tee` to duplicate the original generator, then split one of the copies to get just the data.

```
sample1, sample2 = itertools.tee(sample_generator, 2)
processed_data_generator = process_data_generator(d for (l,d) in sample1)
processed_sample_generator = sample2
```

Comment: If `processed_sample_generator` is just the same as `sample_generator`, I don't think it's "processed" much...

Answer (score 0):

Flatten the `sample_generator` and have both `label_generator` and `data_generator` take from it:

```
import itertools
label_generator = data_generator = itertools.chain.from_iterable(sample_generator)
```

Comment: For processing I have an existing non-changeable API :/

Comment: @TimJoseph That would've been good to know. Anyway, have a look again, I replaced my solution with a completely different one.